# Skype unmet dependencies, can't install

Tags: apt, skype, dependencies, software-installation

I looked around a bit for some solutions first, but they didn't seem to work due to another issue.

first of all, i freshly installed ubuntu 13.10 yesterday, did my updates and upgrades etc.

so this is a fairly new/fresh system.

when i try to install skype I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

when I add the canonical partners using this line:

```
apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

and update, I get this:

```
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

`apt-get -f install` didn't do anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: how are you trying to install Skype? there's no currently Skype for 13.10 only for LTS versions you can download Skype for 12.04 from its [official website](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue these commands:

```
sudo rm -fR /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

After that it will work.